# Efficiently determine all working items given delay and probability of working

Tags: probability, optimization

This is from a real-life problem and I'm trying to find a more efficient solution.

I have:

- a computer
- $n$ RAM sticks (120 in my case), some of which are defective
- the probability $p$ of a working, non-defective RAM stick (60% in my case)
- the computer boot time $t$ (1 minute in my case)

To check if a RAM stick is working (not defective), the process is:

- insert RAM stick (assume this takes a negligible amount of time)
- boot up the computer (assume $t = 60 seconds$)
- visually check for errors on screen (assume this takes a negligible amount of time)
- turn off computer (assume this takes a negligible amount of time)

In my case, I could do the following sequence:

- insert first RAM stick
- boot up computer
- visually check for errors on screen
- turn off computer
- replace first RAM stick with second
- boot up computer
- visually check for errors on screen
- turn off computer
- replace second RAM stick with third
- $\ldots$

In my case, this would take $n \times t = 120 * 60 seconds = 2 hours$.

Is there a more efficient way to determine all working, non-defective RAM stick given that I know the probability $p$ of it working is $60\%$?

If I do two at a time (and remove one at random if an error occurs) in real life, it seems like it is quicker, but I don't know the formula for the calculation of time.

Both practical methods that would work for a human and theoretical methods (requiring lots of bookkeeping) are welcome for this question.

Clarifications:

- if any of the RAM sticks in the computer are defective, then an error occurs. It does not say how many nor which ones are not working

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem is called [group testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_testing).

One simple approach is to test $k>1$ at a time.  If there is no error, you know that all $k$ are good.  Otherwise, at least one is bad, and you test each one individually.  The expected number of tests is $$\frac{120}{k}(1+(1-0.6^k)k),$$
and this is $>120$ for all $k>1$.

With $p=0.7$ instead of $p=0.6$, you can check that $k=3$ is best.  With even higher success probabilities, you can achieve much better than $120$ tests.

A better but more complicated approach is to use dynamic programming.  Let value function $V(e,u)$ be the minimum expected number of tests when you have $e$ sticks that were part of a pool that yielded an error and $u$ sticks that are unknown except by distribution.  You want to compute $V(0,120)$.  The DP recursion is
\begin{align}
V(0,0) &= 0 \\
V(1,u) &= V(0,u) \\
V(0,u) &= 1+\min_{1\le k \le u} \{p^k V(0,u-k)+(1-p^k) V(k,u-k)\} &&\text{if $u>0$}\\
V(e,u) &= 1+\min_{1\le k \le e-1} \left\{\frac{p^k-p^e}{1-p^e} V(e-k,u)+\frac{1-p^k}{1-p^e} V(k,u+e-k)\right\} &&\text{if $e>1$ and $u\ge0$}
\end{align}